# Unable to get Unity OnTriggerEnter2D to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried following a few tutorials for Unity Collision and I am not sure how to get this to work, whatever I do I cannot get this to output the Debug.Log portion.

[Tower Object Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnVgg.png)
[Enemy Object Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATcEe.png)

My Code is this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
   if (collision.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy Arrived");
    }
    
}
```

}

I also attempted without The tower as a trigger with OnCollision instead to no avail. Or Detecting Range based off a youtube tutorial. But None of them seem to detect the Game Object and write out to the Debug Log.

Comment: and which script is that trigger code from?

Comment: maybe `RigidBody` component on your enermy object shoudl set to `Kinematic` or `Dynamic` type?

Comment: When using trigger tests, make sure at least one of your objects has a rigidbody and that only one of the 2 objects is a trigger and the other is not.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps maybe the tag is not correct? Make sure that the tag is correct! It is case-sensitive!